# Super / Child classes / Shared variables

Tags: python-3.x, class, super

I've got 2 classes (Post_data and Get_data) where I would like to get common variables from another class (Main).

From what I read in the documentation, super() seems to be adapted to achieve that.

Indeed, the variable self.tempFile is gotten in both classes. However, 2 instances are created, when I would like to get only one (as you probably understood, my point is to create a temporary file and perform several operations on it in both classes).

```
from tempfile import mkstemp

class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        fd, self.tempFile = mkstemp()

class Post_data(Main):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def save_data(self):
        print(self.tempFile)

class Get_data(Main):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def open_datafile(self):
        print(self.tempFile)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Post_data().save_data() 
    Get_data().open_datafile()
```

Do you know how I could get only one instance of the object self.tempFile ?
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: For such a usecase, you should follow `dependency injection` principle. The idea is Main object should be passed to init of Post_data and Get_data

Comment: If you want to create *a single temporary file* then just pass it as a *dependancy* to your other classes, don't use a mixin. You could probably do that but that is totally an over-engineered way to doing what you are trying to do.